# Entity Framework using SQL Server datastore modelling a one-to-many relationship

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

Can I get some help diagnosing the following?

```
IQueryable<MyComponentsViewModel> vcvm = from v1 in pg.MyComponents 
                                         join item in Items on v1.Item equals item into vc
                                         select new MyComponentsViewModel 
                                                    {  Cost = item.Cost };
```

The following error appears:

> Error CS1941: The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is
>   incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'.

Is this error state occuring as item is not the same type as v1.Item?

The keys are shown below

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyComponents]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[FK_MyComponents_Items] FOREIGN KEY([ItemId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Items] ([Itemid])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyComponents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MyComponents_Items]
```

Comment: that is not SQL related question.

Comment: It may come from a dependency since the datastore is sql server and requires keying. Is there a better tag?

Comment: Have you tried to google your error?

Comment: Yes and it came to like most things stackoverflow but a post I found unrelated. Are you able to provide any helpful feedback?

Comment: Sorry, I'm SQL guy

Answer (score 1):

I assume like, you need inner join and while you doing equals you need to use their matching column Ids to filter records like below

```
IQueryable<MyComponentsViewModel> vcvm = 
    from myComp in pg.MyComponents 
    join item in Items on myComp.ItemId equals item.Id
    select new MyComponentsViewModel {   Cost = item.Cost };
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm thinking the foreign keys enable entity framework to know the relationships automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work.

There was an ambiguity between an action named Items. Fully specify the namespace resolved this.
Additionally I had to add the statement "from subitem in vc.DefaultIfEmpty"

I'm still working to learn the full semantics of this

```
IQueryable<MyComponentsViewModel> vcvm = 
    from v1 in pg.MyComponents 
    join item in pg.Items on v1.Item equals item into vc
    from subitem in vc.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new MyComponentsViewModel {   Cost = subitem.Cost };
```